# Strange font behavior with external monitors on MacBook

Tags: terminal, display, textmate, font

I have noticed some strange behavior when using an external monitor with my MacBook and DejaVu Sans Mono (or Panic Sans) with Terminal.app and TextMate.

If I launch these programs prior to plugging in an external monitor, when I plug in the monitor, the fonts appear [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unKLc.png).

However, if I plug in the monitor first, and then open the application, the fonts are displayed [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvHaK.png).

Is there some way to ensure that the bolder, clearer version is always displayed, regardless of when I plug in an external monitor?

Note: I have noticed this behavior on many different monitors, connected via both DVI and VGA.

Thank you.

~Arun

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with Xcode. Unfortunately, it stuck even after disconnecting the monitor and I had to reinstall Xcode. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079590/xcode-4-source-editor-not-displaying-text-properly/6088426#6088426

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has to do with LCD font smoothing.

[This Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090828224632809) tip describes how to fix the problem:

> In Snow Leopard, you can only choose between Automatic and Standard CRT. Since few people use CRTs these days, most users now have only one option: Automatic. The problem with the Automatic option is that OS X incorrectly detects many third party LCD monitors as CRTs, and consequently, disables LCD font smoothing.
>
> You can force OS X to use LCD font smoothing on all displays with this Terminal command:
>
> `defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 2`
>
> The number `2` here corresponds to Medium - Best for Flat Panel. You may also use 1 for light smoothing, and 3 for strong smoothing, as per the original OS X font smoothing options.

<s>You might have to re-login (maybe even restart) for this to take effect.</s>

Comment: No need to restart; you just need to relaunch the apps in question.